# Get HREF value with loaded page

Tags: jquery

I have this content inside a html page : mypage.html

```
<a href="http://site1" target="_blank" class="hrefClass" id="href_id1"><here an image></a>
<a href="http://site2" target="_blank" class="hrefClass" id="href_id2"><here an image></a>
```

this content id loaded via:

```
$('#myContent').load('mypage.html');
```

When I click on img_link, I would like to have the href.

e.g: If I click on img1, I would like to retrieve 'http://site1'

How could I do that ?

I alreday tried:

```
$('.hrefClass > img').live("click", function() {          
    alert(this.id);      
});
```

But no success. In fact with the previous code, nothing is triggered... I have no 'alert'.

Comment: change this.id to 'foo' or something and see if you still don't get an alert, that will at least tell you if your click event is being wired up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$('.hrefClass > img').live("click", function()
{          
    alert($(this).parent().attr("href"));  

    return false;    
});
```

An example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJPqJ/).

The `$(this)` portion points to the image onto which the user clicked, the `parent()` function finds the immediate parent of the clicked image, and the `attr()` function gets the `href` attribute value of that parent.

Finally, the `return false` statement ensures that the default action of the link, which is opening up another url, doesn't happen. If you want to allow the default action, then omit this return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HBsAV/

#### HTML

```
<a href="#"><img id="img_link" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/>Click Here</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$("a").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("href"));
});

$("#img_link").click(function(event){
   alert($(this).attr("src"));
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$('.hrefClass').live('click', function() {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));   
});
```

If this Javascript is contained in mypage.html, you can load it something like this..

```
(function($){
jQuery.fn.myload = function(url){
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
            self.html(data);
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Load..

```
$('#mypage').myload('mypage.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback function of load() so that it runs after the load has happened.

e.g.

```
$('#mycontent').load('/mypage.html', function() {
  $('.hrefClass > img').live("click", function() { alert(this.id); });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more details on jQuery.load()

Comment: change the alert to be alert($(this).attr('id'))

Answer (score 0):

In your `click` event handler, `this` will reference the element that was clicked, which is likely to be the image. Therefore, it won't have an `id` or `href` attribute (hence why you see no alert when using `id`).

You can use the `closest` function to search the DOM tree and get the closest `a` element to the clicked element, and then get the `href` attribute:

```
$('.hrefClass > img').live("click", function() {          
    alert($(this).closest("a").attr("href"));      
});
```

See a working example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bDfY/).

Comment: AFAIK, if you click on image `img` without clicking on anchor `a`, so I don't see point why should trigger be on `img` and not on `a`...

Comment: I noticed that $('.hrefClass > img') do not trigger any event: It's only if I put $('#myContent'), but in this case it return me 'undefined'

Comment: I'm really sorry... I'm working on several pages (to be loaded), I forgot the add the class name to the <a href> tag. Of course your code fit !!! Thanks for your time and sorry for my incapacity !

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery.livequery a nice plugin

Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated.[1]

```
$('.hrefClass').livequery('click', function(event) { 
    alert('clicked'); 
    return false; 
});
```

This binds the 'click' event to each matched element newly inserted into the DOM,
even if you `append()` created DOMElements by hand.

[1] Taken from https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery